# Java enum-based state machine (FSM): Passing in events

Tags: java, enums, fsm, state-machine

I'm using several enum-based state machines in my Android application. While these work very well, what I am looking for is a suggestion for how to elegantly receive events, typically from registered callbacks or from eventbus messages, into the currently active state. Of the many blogs and tutorials concerning enum-based FSMs, most of them give examples of state machines that consume data (e.g. parsers) rather than show how these FSMs may be driven from events.

A typical state machine I'm using has this form:

```
private State mState;

public enum State {

    SOME_STATE {


        init() {
         ... 
        }


        process() {
         ... 
        }


    },


    ANOTHER_STATE {

        init() {
         ... 
        }

        process() {
         ... 
        }

    }

}

...
```

In my situation, some of the states trigger a piece of work to be done on a particular object, registering a listener. That object asynchronously calls back when the work is done. In other words, just a simple callback interface.

Similarly, I have an EventBus. Classes wanting to be notified of events again implement a callback interface and `listen()` for those event types on the EventBus.

The basic problem therefore is that the state machine, or its individual states, or the class containing the enum FSM, or *something* has to implement those callback interfaces, so that they can represent events on the current state.

One approach I have used is for the entire `enum` to implement the callback interface(s). The enum itself has default implementations of the callback methods at the bottom, and the individual states can then override those callback methods for events they're interested in. For this to work, each state must register and unregister as it enters and exits, otherwise there is risk of the callback happening on a state that isn't the current state. I will probably stick with this if I find nothing better.

Another way is for the containing class to implement the callbacks. It then has to delegate those events on to the state machine, by calling `mState.process( event )`. That means I'd need to enumerate event types. For example:

```
enum Events {
    SOMETHING_HAPPENED,
    ...
}

...

onSometingHappened() {

    mState.process( SOMETHING_HAPPENED );
}
```

I don't like this however because (a) I'd have the uglyness of needing to `switch` on the event types within the `process(event)` of each state, and (b) passing through additional parameters looks awkward.

I would like a suggestion for an elegant solution for this without resorting to using a library.

Comment: Elegant in what way? What aspect of the previous solutions would you like improved?

Comment: Hi meriton! Good point; I ought to amend the question to clarify. What I envisaged was a situation where the actual `enum`s themselves could implement the listener interfaces in such a way that avoids need to listen and dispatch events onwards from the outer context to the current state `enum`. In other words, is there a way to avoid effectively defining and listening on events twice over. I realise this is an unrealistic or impossible ask. Although some clever ideas have been put forward (such as dudeprgm's), I'm leaning towards staying with the current code which is based on your answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

So you want to dispatch events to their handlers for the current state.

To dispatch to the current state, subscribing each state as it becomes active, and unsubscribing it as it becomes inactive is rather cumbersome. It is easier to subscribe an object that knows the active state, and simply delegates all events to the active state.

To distinguish events, you can use separate event objects, and then distinguish them with the [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), but that's quite a bit of boilerplate code. I'd only do this if I have other code that treats all events the same (for instance, if events must be buffered before delivery). Otherwise, I'd simply do something like

```
interface StateEventListener {
    void onEventX();
    void onEventY(int x, int y);
    void onEventZ(String s);
}

enum State implements StateEventListener {
    initialState {
        @Override public void onEventX() {
            // do whatever
        }
        // same for other events
    },
    // same for other states
}

class StateMachine implements StateEventListener {
    State currentState;

    @Override public void onEventX() {
        currentState.onEventX();
    }

    @Override public void onEventY(int x, int y) {
        currentState.onEventY(x, y);
    }

    @Override public void onEventZ(String s) {
        currentState.onEventZ(s);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

If you have many event types, it might be better to generate the boring delegation code at runtime using a bytecode engineering library, or even a plain JDK proxy:

```
class StateMachine2 {
    State currentState;

    final StateEventListener stateEventPublisher = buildStateEventForwarder(); 

    StateEventListener buildStateEventForwarder() {
        Class<?>[] interfaces = {StateEventListener.class};
        return (StateEventListener) Proxy.newProxyInstance(getClass().getClassLoader(), interfaces, new InvocationHandler() {
            @Override
            public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
                try {
                    return method.invoke(currentState, args);
                } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                    throw e.getCause();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

This makes the code less readable, but does eliminate the need to write delegation code for each event type.

Comment: Thank you - much appreciated. You've got me thinking now - I'm wondering if, instead of manually writing `class StateMachine` to implement the same `interface`s and delegate events forward to `currentState`, could it be possible to automate this using reflection (or something). Example: each `enum` state could have a method `registerForEventTypes` which returns listener `class`es it's interested in. Then the outer class would register as a listener for those classes at runtime and delegate them on, and register/unregister the state as it enters/exits. (Ignore me, just thinking out loud here.)

Comment: It would probably be easier to always deliver events, and provide a default implementation of the listener methods that does nothing. And yes, you could use byte code generation to automate writing the delegation methods, for instance with a `java.lang.reflect.Proxy`, or a full fledged byte code engineering library such as Javassist. For less than a dozen event types however, it is probably easier and clearer to write the code by hand.

Comment: Isn't using a proxy and invoking methods using reflection going to be slow, especially on a mobile Android device?

Comment: That depends on how often such state transitions occur. I'd expect you could forward millions of state transitions per second using this approach.

Comment: Minor points: In your `StateMachine`, you'll want to 1) implement `StateEventListener` and 2) make the methods public in both the `State` and `StateMachine`

Answer (score 28):

Why not have events call the right callback on state directly?

```
public enum State {
   abstract State processFoo();
   abstract State processBar();
   State processBat() { return this; } // A default implementation, so that states that do not use this event do not have to implement it anyway.
   ...
   State1 {
     State processFoo() { return State2; }
     ...
   },
   State2 {
      State processFoo() { return State1; }
      ...
   } 
}

public enum  Event {
   abstract State dispatch(State state);
   Foo {
      State dispatch(State s) { return s.processFoo(); }
   },
   Bar {
      State dispatch(State s) { return s.processBar(); }
   }
   ...
}
```

This addresses both of your reservations with the original approach: no "ugly" switch, and no "awkward" additional parameters.

Comment: This comes to the same thing as @meriton's answer. All states _must_ implement _all_ events, even if the don't use them. This is what the OP was trying to avoid.

Comment: Not really. You can provide a default implementation for that. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 7):

You are on good tracks, you should use a [Strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) combined with your state machine. Implement event handling in your state enum, providing a default common implementation and possibly add specific implementations.

Define your events and the associated strategy interface  :

```
enum Event
{
    EVENT_X,
    EVENT_Y,
    EVENT_Z;
    // Other events...
}

interface EventStrategy
{
    public void onEventX();
    public void onEventY();
    public void onEventZ();
    // Other events...
}
```

Then, in your `State` enum :

```
enum State implements EventStrategy
{
    STATE_A
    {
        @Override
        public void onEventX()
        {
            System.out.println("[STATE_A] Specific implementation for event X");
        }
    },

    STATE_B
    {
        @Override
        public void onEventY()
        {
            System.out.println("[STATE_B] Default implementation for event Y");     
        }

        public void onEventZ()
        {
            System.out.println("[STATE_B] Default implementation for event Z");
        }
    };
    // Other states...      

    public void process(Event e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Google Guava is used here
            Method listener = this.getClass().getMethod("on" + CaseFormat.UPPER_UNDERSCORE.to(CaseFormat.UPPER_CAMEL, e.name()));
            listener.invoke(this);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Missing event handling or something went wrong
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The event " + e.name() + " is not handled in the state machine", ex);
        }
    }

    // Default implementations

    public void onEventX()
    {
        System.out.println("Default implementation for event X");
    }

    public void onEventY()
    {
        System.out.println("Default implementation for event Y");       
    }

    public void onEventZ()
    {
        System.out.println("Default implementation for event Z");
    }
}
```

According to `EventStrategy`, there is a default implementation for all events. Moreover, for each state, a specific implementation, for a different event handling, is possible.

The `StateMachine` would look like that :

```
class StateMachine
{
    // Active state
    State mState;

    // All the code about state change

    public void onEvent(Event e)
    {
        mState.process(e);
    }
}
```

In this scenario, you trust mState being the current active state, all events are applied on this state only. If you want to add a security layer, to disable all events for all non active states, you can do it but in my opinion, it's not a good pattern, it's not up to a `State` to know if it's active but it's `StateMachine` job.

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear to me why you need a callback interface when you already have an event bus. The bus should be able to deliver events to listeners based on the event type without the need for interfaces. Consider an architecture like [Guava's](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained) (I know you don't want to resort to external libraries, it's the design what I want to bring to your attention).

```
enum State {
  S1 {
    @Subscribe void on(EventX ex) { ... }
  },
  S2 {
    @Subscribe void on(EventY ey) { ... }
  }
}

// when a state becomes active
eventBus.register(currentState);
eventBus.unregister(previousState);
```

I believe this approach goes along the lines of your first comment to meriton's answer:

> Instead of manually writing class StateMachine to implement the  same interfaces and delegate events forward to currentState, it could be possible to automate this using reflection (or something). Then the outer class would register as a listener for those classes at runtime and delegate them on, and register/unregister the state as it enters/exits.

Answer (score 4):

You may want to try using the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern): the Command interface corresponds to something like your "SOMETHING_HAPPENED". Each enum value, then, is instantiated with a particular command, which may be instantiated via Reflection and can run the execute method (defined in the Command interface).

If useful, consider also the [State pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

If commands are complex, consider also the [Composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern).

Comment: Thanks Manu. I will look into these patterns and suggestions now.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative for Java 8 might be to use an interface with default methods, like this:

```
public interface IPositionFSM {

    default IPositionFSM processFoo() {
        return this;
    }

    default IPositionFSM processBar() {
        return this;
    }
}

public enum PositionFSM implements IPositionFSM {
    State1 {
        @Override
        public IPositionFSM processFoo() {
            return State2;
        }
    },
    State2 {
        @Override
        public IPositionFSM processBar() {
            return State1;
        }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about implementing event handling with Visitors:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class StateMachine {
    interface Visitor {
        void visited(State state);
    }

    enum State {
        // a to A, b to B
        A('a',"A",'b',"B"),
        // b to B, b is an end-state
        B('b',"B") {
            @Override
            public boolean endState() { return true; }
        },
        ;

        private final Map<Character,String> transitions = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        private State(Object...transitions) {
            for(int i=0;i<transitions.length;i+=2)
                this.transitions.put((Character) transitions[i], (String) transitions[i+1]);
        }
        private State transition(char c) {
            if(!transitions.containsKey(c))
                throw new IllegalStateException("no transition from "+this+" for "+c);
            return State.valueOf(transitions.get(c)).visit();
        }
        private State visit() {
            for(Visitor visitor : visitors)
                visitor.visited(this);
            return this;
        }
        public boolean endState() { return false; }
        private final List<Visitor> visitors = new LinkedList<>();
        public final void addVisitor(Visitor visitor) {
            visitors.add(visitor);
        }
        public State process(String input) {
            State state = this;
            for(char c : input.toCharArray())
                state = state.transition(c);
            return state;
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String input = "aabbbb";

        Visitor commonVisitor = new Visitor() {
            @Override
            public void visited(State state) {
                System.out.println("visited "+state);
            }
        };

        State.A.addVisitor(commonVisitor);
        State.B.addVisitor(commonVisitor);

        State state = State.A.process(input);

        System.out.println("endState = "+state.endState());
    }
}
```

The state-diagram definition and event-handling code look rather minimal in my opinion. :)  And, with a little more work, it can be made to work with a generic input type.

Answer (score 2):

Well this is an old question but for the people who stumbles on it via Google search, while nobody mentioned here, I will advice to check two existing frameworks before you implement you own State Machines with Java Enumerations.

One is [Spring State Machine](https://docs.spring.io/spring-statemachine/docs/current/reference/), which you can model your State and Events as enumerations, most of you are familiar with Spring framework, which allow us to use several features of Spring like dependency injection and everything else that Spring can offer.

It is really great for modelling the lifecycle of an Apparat, with states like INITIALIZING, STARTED, ERROR, RECOVERING, SHUTTINGDOWN, etc.. but I see lots of people are trying to model a Shopping Chart, a Reservation System with it, the memory footprint a Spring State Machine is relatively big to model millions of Shopping Charts or Reservations.

One other disadvantage, with Spring State Machine, while has a capability to persist itself for long running processes but it does not have any mechanism to adapt to changes in these processes, if you persist a process and you have to recover it lets say 10 days later with a change happened in the business process because of new software release / requirements, you have no built in means to deal with it.

I have several blogs, [blog1](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2015/12/14/ajax-spring-web-flow-and-spring-state-machine/) [blog2](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2016/01/20/xtext-domain-specific-language-and-spring-state-machine/), demonstrating how you can program Spring State Machine, specially model driven way if you want to check it.

But mainly because the disadvantages I mentioned before, I advice you to look another framework first, [Akka FSM](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/fsm.html) (Finite State Machine) which is more fitting with its low memory footprint to have millions and millions of instances and has a capability to adapt changing long running processes.

Now you can develop with Akka framework with Java but believe me because of some missing language elements, you don't want to read the code, Scala is a much more fitting language to develop with Akka with its Case Classes (which looks a lot similar to Java Enumeration) and powerful pattern matching capabilities with Switch statements.

Now I hear you saying Scala is too complex, I can't convince my project leads to develop with Scala, to convince you all this is an option, I developed a Proof of Concept application using a Java/Scala hybrid with all Scala Akka Finite State Machine code generated from an UML model, if you want to check it out here the links to the blogs, [blog3](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/04/18/a-model-driven-event-sourced-cloud-ready-application-with-akka-finite-state-machine-using-kafka-cassandra-and-elasticsearch/) [blog4](https://mehmetsalgar.wordpress.com/2022/05/17/model-driven-akka-finite-state-machine-fsm/).

I hope this information would help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am unable to make any comment at this time in relation to my original question because I am not actively working on the project now; it's all a bit of a distant hazy memory!

Answer (score 0):

Simple example if you do not have events and just need next status 
    public enum LeaveRequestState {

```
    Submitted {
        @Override
        public LeaveRequestState nextState() {
            return Escalated;
        }

        @Override
        public String responsiblePerson() {
            return "Employee";
        }
    },
    Escalated {
        @Override
        public LeaveRequestState nextState() {
            return Approved;
        }

        @Override
        public String responsiblePerson() {
            return "Team Leader";
        }
    },
    Approved {
        @Override
        public LeaveRequestState nextState() {
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public String responsiblePerson() {
            return "Department Manager";
        }
    };

    public abstract LeaveRequestState nextState(); 
    public abstract String responsiblePerson();
}
```