# Framework for defining processes and activities for Java

Tags: java, business-process-management

I wonder if there is some framework or api or whatever to define business processes and activities for a java application, which allows to manage them (add, remove, trace etc.).

I am currently structuring my java application and try to define and keep eye on business processes in my application and I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Is something like that already implemented out there??

Comment: Have a look at this topic, it may somewhat answer this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474294/lightweight-workflow-engine-for-java

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at Bonita and especially Activity. Both are open-source.

https://www.activiti.org

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonita_BPM