# Observer Subject Singleton pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, singleton, observer-pattern

I'm working on designing a pattern where there will be multiple subjects and multiple observers. Each observer will register itself to the subjects that it needs to in it's constructor, as it knows what it needs to know to produce it's output. My first thought was to make the subjects a singleton class, but I found that would either require making each subject a singleton individually, or an `abstract static` class that Java does not support. Bottom line is, I'm trying to figure out what the best solution really is. Just to make sure it's really clear, here's what I'm trying to do:

1. There will be multiple subjects. Each observer will have the ability to observe multiple subjects. In order to make this work, I'm going to have a resource code for each subject such that it will identify itself to the Observer (`update(SUBJECT_1) where SUBJECT_1 is the int that corresponds to Subject 1)
2. Each observer will know which subjects it wants to observe at construction.
3. I only want a single instance of each subject created.
4. Some observers might in turn be subjects themselves.
5. In general, there is a flow pattern. There is ultimately a few sources of input, which create more abstract concepts. My flow diagram of observer/subject looks something like this:

[image]

I'm thinking this might call for another design pattern entirely, but as I'm still fairly new to design patterns in general, I thought I'd ask for a bit more experience before I jump in. Thanks!

Just to be clear, the singleton comes in to play as follows, namely that I want an abstractSubject, where every subject is a Singleton. While I could make each a singleton of its own accord, I'd rather be forced to make all use a getInstance, something like this psuedo-code.

```
abstract class abstractSubject{

AbstractSubject instance=null;

public static AbstractSubject getInstance()
{
    if (instance==null)
        instance=new AbstractInstance();
    return instance;
}
abstract void attach();
//More stuff will go here to make it a subject
}

//Define Subject1, Subject2 classes fully

class Observer1 extends AbstractObserver{

    public Observer1()
    {
        Subject1.getInstance().attach(this);
        Subject2.getInstance().attach(this);
    }
    //Other stuff goes here to make it an observer
}
```

Comment: I fail to see where the singleton comes into play. How about an enum that holds all the different posibilities?

Comment: AFAIR this design pattern is called Observer/observable and the observable does NOT have the restrictions that you mentioned. Why is your design suffering here?

Comment: I've tried to be a bit clearer with an example of what I'm hoping to accomplish. Hope that helps.

Comment: You cannot make a singleton abstract, that goes against the entire idea of a singleton. Abstract classes can't be instantiated. You will have to define everything of the singleton in a subclass (although you might be better off with a "standalone" class an an interface for the methods). I'm not entirely sure if it's possible to define `getInstance()` in an interface.

Comment: The way of your using or thinking about using Singleton is entirely WRONG. Trust me, dont even try it, it does not solve anything, but it can have terrible consequences in the future.

Comment: I understand that using Singletons is wrong and won't work, but I do like the ability to not have to worry about having the observers talk directly to the subject to get an instance. I'm just trying to figure out what would work along the same lines, but be better overall.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto: you could create one central singleton that holds a `HashSet<Observer, List<Subject>>` where you can define what observers observer what subjects. That way they don't know about eachother and you have only one central instance.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: I like where that is going. That's similar to what I'm thinking I will do, which I just posted as an answer to my question. Essentially, I'll have a central class that keeps track of all of the subjects creates them if required, and returns them, which I've called the Broker. This central class will likely be a singleton as well. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After thinking this through a bit, the best thing seems to be to have a pattern that looks like this, that I think is something related to either the Builder or Factory class, but I'm still trying to work out how it works.

1. There is a third party class whose job it is to keep track of all of the subjects that are created, and provide references to them if asked. For lack of a better term, I'll call it the Broker.
2. Each observer has access to this Broker. They ask the Broker for what they want, and it creates the object if it hasn't been instantiated yet.

If all observers are constructed to use this Broker, then they just have to know the call to get the Broker to return what they want, which should be simple enough. The Broker will need to be updated every time a new Subject is created, but it otherwise seems the cleanest way I can come up with to make this all work.

In addition, the Broker Class contains an Enum that contains all of the subjects, thus, it can act as an efficient point to keep track of the Enum values that correspond to a given class.

This looks something like:

```
public class Broker {
    public enum Subject {Subj1, Subj2};

    static private Broker instance=null;

    HashMap<Subject,AbstractSubject> mSubjectDict;

    public static Broker getInstance()
    {
        return instance;
    }

    private Broker()
    {
        mSubjectDict=new HashMap<Subject,AbstractSubject>();
        mSubjectDict.put(Subject.Subj1,new Subject1());
        mSubjectDict.put(Subject.Subj2,new Subject2());
    }

    public AbstractLocationSubject getSubject(Subject subj)
    {
        return mSubjectDict.get(subj);
    }
}
```

All adding a new possible Subject requires is adding a value to the Enum, and creating the Subject in the mSubjectDict. Overall, I'm content with this solution.

Answer (score 0):

I really dont get, why you even think about a Singleton. It does not help you with anything in observer pattern. Avoid Singleton at all cost until you are very good programmer or you really dont see any other reasanoble choice.

The approach of notyfing some observers and some not based on hardcoded numbers is really non-OOP.

You can create enum called "Quests" for example and each observer will have its own list of values from that enum. When you are notyfing observers from subject or subjects, you just go through the whole list of registered observers and notyfing them based on that enum (or you can notify all, having this enum as parameter of notyfing as a message and you can let observers decide, if they do anything).

EDIT (based on added 5. to your post) : Well it does not look like you really need the Observer pattern, it is usually used as handler of events. If your data flow from one instance to other and you know how how it will flow etc., the Observer is not really needed. I dont know what exactly you are doing with a data, you can think about Chain of Responsibility.

However if your instances just recieving messages, counting them, then send next messages to other instances, at least the idea of observer - registering and notyfing - is good approach.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to build a workflow engine?

There are lots of those out there already:
[Which Java based workflow engine should I use?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7643050/42962)

I'm also going to add Spring Integration and Spring Batch to the list.

Answer (score 0):

I can't talk for Java, but I have encountered a similar type of problem in C++.

Here is the rough sketch of what I came up with as a solution.  It is written in C++, but the basic ideas should translate well to Java (or other OO languages for that matter):

1. The Observer is a singleton with keys (enumerated values, not strings; this is a speed tradeoff since the keys are not searched hashed, but it means no easy "string" names and you have to define them ahead of time) for Subjects to register interest in.  Because it is a singleton, it always exists.
2. Each subject is derived from a common base class.  The base class has an abstract virtual function Notify(...) which must be implemented in derived classes, and a destructor that removes it from the Observer (which it can always reach) when it is deleted.
3. Inside the Observer itself, if Detach(...) is called while a Notify(...) is in progress, any detached Subjects end up on a list.
4. When Notify(...) is called on the Observer, it creates a temporary copy of the Subject list.  As it iterates over it, it compare it to the recently detached.  If the target is not on it, Notify(...) is called on the target.  Otherwise, it is skipped.
5. Notify(...) in the Observer also keeps track of the depth to handle cascading calls (A notifies B, C, D, and the D.Notify(...) triggers a Notify(...) call to E, etc.)

This is what the interface ended up looking like:

```
/* 
 The Notifier is a singleton implementation of the Subject/Observer design
 pattern.  Any class/instance which wishes to participate as an observer
 of an event can derive from the Notified base class and register itself
 with the Notiifer for enumerated events.

 Notifier derived classes MUST implement the notify function, which has 
 a prototype of:

 void Notify(const NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T& event)

 This is a data object passed from the Notifier class.  The structure 
 passed has a void* in it.  There is no illusion of type safety here 
 and it is the responsibility of the user to ensure it is cast properly.
 In most cases, it will be "NULL".

 Classes derived from Notified do not need to deregister (though it may 
 be a good idea to do so) as the base class destructor will attempt to
 remove itself from the Notifier system automatically.

 The event type is an enumeration and not a string as it is in many 
 "generic" notification systems.  In practical use, this is for a closed
 application where the messages will be known at compile time.  This allows
 us to increase the speed of the delivery by NOT having a 
 dictionary keyed lookup mechanism.  Some loss of generality is implied 
 by this.

 This class/system is NOT thread safe, but could be made so with some
 mutex wrappers.  It is safe to call Attach/Detach as a consequence 
 of calling Notify(...).  

 */


class Notified;

class Notifier : public SingletonDynamic<Notifier>
{
public:
   typedef enum
   {
      NE_MIN = 0,
      NE_DEBUG_BUTTON_PRESSED = NE_MIN,
      NE_DEBUG_LINE_DRAW_ADD_LINE_PIXELS,
      NE_DEBUG_TOGGLE_VISIBILITY,
      NE_DEBUG_MESSAGE,
      NE_RESET_DRAW_CYCLE,
      NE_VIEWPORT_CHANGED,
      NE_MAX,
   } NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T;

private:
   typedef vector<NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T> NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_VECTOR_T;

   typedef map<Notified*,NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_VECTOR_T> NOTIFIED_MAP_T;
   typedef map<Notified*,NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_VECTOR_T>::iterator NOTIFIED_MAP_ITER_T;

   typedef vector<Notified*> NOTIFIED_VECTOR_T;
   typedef vector<NOTIFIED_VECTOR_T> NOTIFIED_VECTOR_VECTOR_T;

   NOTIFIED_MAP_T _notifiedMap;
   NOTIFIED_VECTOR_VECTOR_T _notifiedVector;
   NOTIFIED_MAP_ITER_T _mapIter;

   // This vector keeps a temporary list of observers that have completely
   // detached since the current "Notify(...)" operation began.  This is
   // to handle the problem where a Notified instance has called Detach(...)
   // because of a Notify(...) call.  The removed instance could be a dead
   // pointer, so don't try to talk to it.
   vector<Notified*> _detached;
   int32 _notifyDepth;

   void RemoveEvent(NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_VECTOR_T& orgEventTypes, NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType);
   void RemoveNotified(NOTIFIED_VECTOR_T& orgNotified, Notified* observer);

public:

   virtual void Reset();
   virtual bool Init() { Reset(); return true; }
   virtual void Shutdown() { Reset(); }

   void Attach(Notified* observer, NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType);
   // Detach for a specific event
   void Detach(Notified* observer, NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType);
   // Detach for ALL events
   void Detach(Notified* observer);

   /* The design of this interface is very specific.  I could 
    * create a class to hold all the event data and then the
    * method would just have take that object.  But then I would
    * have to search for every place in the code that created an
    * object to be used and make sure it updated the passed in
    * object when a member is added to it.  This way, a break
    * occurs at compile time that must be addressed.
    */
   void Notify(NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T, const void* eventData = NULL);

   /* Used for CPPUnit.  Could create a Mock...maybe...but this seems
    * like it will get the job done with minimal fuss.  For now.
    */
   // Return all events that this object is registered for.
   vector<NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T> GetEvents(Notified* observer);
   // Return all objects registered for this event.
   vector<Notified*> GetNotified(NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T event);
};

/* This is the base class for anything that can receive notifications.
 */
class Notified
{
public:
   virtual void Notify(Notifier::NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType, const void* eventData) = 0;
   virtual ~Notified();

};

typedef Notifier::NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T;
```

NOTE:  The Notified class has a single function, Notify(...) here.  Because the void* is not type safe, I created other versions where notify looks like:

```
virtual void Notify(Notifier::NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType, int value); 
virtual void Notify(Notifier::NOTIFIED_EVENT_TYPE_T eventType, const string& str);
```

Corresponding Notify(...) methods were added to the Notifier itself.  All these used a single function to get the "target list" then called the appropriate function on the targets.  This works well and keeps the receiver from having to do ugly casts.

This seems to work well.  The solution is posted on the web [here](http://www.nliapps.com/tools-you-build-part-i-observer/) along with the source code.